# ubuntu mate 20.04, how to change color of "time" in the top bar

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, evolution, clock

I have made the background color in the top bar black and want the clock or time to show in white (the bar is autohide and I want the clock to show when the bar glides down, this worked in 18.04), so it shows on a black background without clicking on it.

It shows when clicking on it in white but only after I click on it otherwise it is just black like the bar.

I assume it is some where in evolution but can not find it including in the ui files.

Comment: is it gnome-shell? ubuntu mate uses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to head to **Appearance Preferences** and then **Customise** and then tinker the **Controls** and **Window Border**. Thanks.

Comment: It is not the border I want to change it is the bar that is autohide where the time is shown. but thanks for taking time to make a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of the process. Thanks.